# Creating angled DIV for hero

Tags: html, css

There's a lot of questions similar to this but they're for edges or have answers incompatible with some browsers. I'd thought of using a gradient image for the background but can achieve the same effect using a background gradient and I'd guess this may be easier to implement with minimal code.

I currently have this, which has flat edges;

```css
.top {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF0000, #00FF00);
}

.main {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

It uses minimal code but I'd be aiming for an angled edge either on the bottom of one and on the top of the other or just the bottom of the top one so that the DIVs match up.

I'd be aiming for something like this…
[image: Example of angled DIVs]

Of course I could rotate the DIV but then there's overflow. I want something clean so that both DIVs match up. Something using `clip-path: polygon` could work but I can't figure out the angles or implementation. Any ideas or resources for where to start would be apprecited.

`UPDATE`

I've figured out how to angle both so that they match up but the DIVs need to be touching for it to look proper.

```css
.top {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF0000, #00FF00);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

.main {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #0000FF;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

`UPDATE 1`
[image: Example with both angled]

Comment: what do you mean there is overflow, when you rotate ?

Comment: If you angle a DIV it skews so you have to correct for that. WebKit polygons could be used on both DIVs but I'm looking for a simple approach

Comment: Looks like you're really close.  Can you make one of the divs `position: absolute` and place it on top of of the other?  `position: relative` might be better because you'd just move the bottom one up about 100px from where it would have been.

Comment: You could just create an SVG matching your needs? This is a much more flexible solution. By the way the overlap of rotated elements can be hidden with `overflow: hidden` on a parent with the same size.

Comment: I have SVGs for the gradients, they just scale more nicely when they're rendered for the screen. As for placing them on top of each other, I could try that

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?  I added `position: relative;` and `top: -150px;` to move it up.

```css
.top {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF0000, #00FF00);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

.main {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
 background: #0000FF;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  position: relative;
  top: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. Ideally they'd not need to be positioned differently and should function as block elements on their angles.